# How many pokécoins can you get from pokémon gyms?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've only ever captured one gym and I got 10 pokécoins immediately and another 10 and 500 stardust after 21 hours. Anyone know how the payout sytem works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get 10 Pokécoins and 500 Stardust for each Gym you are currently, at the point of retrieval, holding. This only works up to 10 Gyms for a total of 100 Pokécoins and 5000 Stardust.
You can retrieve every 21 hours as long as you have a Pokémon in at least 1 Gym.

Therefore it is an efficient tactic to gather as many Gyms as possible in a small timeframe, and at the point you hold the most - retrieve your rewards.

Answer (score 5):

The most you can get is 100 pokecoins and 5000 stardust by holding 10 gyms every 21 hours. If you hold anymore it will not get you any more bonuses.

Comment: As a piggyback to this, the payout is linear. Holding n gyms gives you 10n coins and 500n stardust.

Comment: @Captain thanks, I had hoped the reward would be exponential :(

Comment: Also just to add to that, if you haven't redeemed in the last 21 hours, and you put a Pokemon in a gym, you can perform the redemption immediately. The Pokemon does not need to be in the gym for 21 hours initially, that is just the cooldown.

Comment: What if you hold 10 gyms at different points of the day, each for only 15 minutes?  Do you have to be holding the gym at the time of redemption?

Comment: @Baronz yes you do have be holding the gyms at the time of redemption